# Does there exist any Möbius transformation that preserves upper unit disc?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I know how to find Möbius transformations that preserve unit disc.Can I link my question with that and how? Or maybe Möbius transformations that fix upper unit disc don't exist(exept identity)?Why?

Comment: think how you get $\phi$ to send the real segment $[-1,1]$ to itself and then one of $\pm \phi$ will preserve the upper unit disc and one will switch it with the lower unit disc

Comment: @Conrad , you mean $\phi$ that I already have on Möbius transformation that preserves unit disc?

Comment: So I should find a $\phi$ from $[0,2pi]$ so that the Möbius transformation that I have(which preserves unit disc) preserves real segment $[-1,1]$ ? Will that transformation preserve whole upper unit disc?

Comment: if $-1<r<1$ one of $\pm \frac {z-r}{1-rz}$ will preserve the unit upper unit disc and one will send it to the lower unit disc

Comment: Thank you.Can I find such a transformation that will preserve lower unit disc?

Comment: if the transformation preserves the upper unit disc, it will automatically preserve the lower unit disc too

Comment: umm,yes... Thank you very much for helping me :)

Comment: @Conrad: Unless I am mistaken, the lower unit disk is not preserved if $\phi$ *exchanges* the points $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @Martin you are absolutely right if you allow Mobius transforms that do not preserve the unit disc, only the upper part - the OP question wasn't clear which kind you want (preserve both, only the upper half disc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T$ be a Möbius transformations which maps the upper half of the unit disk into itself. Möbius transformations preserve angles, so that $\{ -1, 1 \}$ must be mapped to $\{ -1, 1 \}$. There are two possibilities:

1. $T(1) = 1$ and $T(-1) = -1$. Then $T$ maps the segment $[-1,1]$ onto itself, so that $T(r) = 0$ for some $r \in (0, 1)$. A simple calculation shows that
   $$
    T(z) = \frac{z-r}{1-rz} \, .
   $$
   In this case, $T$ is the restriction of an automorphism of the unit disk.
2. $T(1) = -1$ and $T(-1) = 1$. Then $T$ maps the upper half of the unit circle onto the segment $[-1, 1]$, so that $T(\lambda) = 0$ for some $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|=1$ and $\operatorname{Im} \lambda > 0$. Now one gets
   $$
    T(z) = \frac{z-\lambda}{\lambda z - 1}  \, .
   $$
   In this case, $T$ is the restriction of a conformal mapping of the unit disk to the upper halfplane.

Comment: So the transformation I'm looking for is in the case 1. Right?

Comment: @Tota: *Both* cases are transformations which preserve the upper unit disk (and that are the only cases, as I tried to demonstrate).

Comment: So I can claim that this transformation preserves both upper and lower unit disc.Can't I?

Comment: @Tota: In case 1 both upper and lower disk is preserved. In case 2 the upper unit disk is preserved (and the lower unit disk is mapped to the complement of the upper disk in the upper halfplane).

Comment: Thank you very much for helping and answering:)